# React - Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint

What is the correct way to avoid this linter message. 'Component definition is missing display name'

The file was created for breadcrumbs and simply export default (with props).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1

Define the component as a variable and then export it

```js
const MyComp = prop => (...)
export default MyComp
```

Option 2

Export the component as a named function

```js
export default function MyComp() {}
```